# A release pipeline is queued with multiple agents idle

Tags: azure-devops

We have an issue where currently we have a single release running and one release queued. Normally this would be ok, but we run self-hosted agents and have currently 9 agents sitting idle to run the release. I keep seeing parallel jobs, but I don't know if that solves this, as this feels more like something that I have misconfigured.

Since this post we have purchased 10 parallel jobs for the self-hosted pool and still are seeing this issue.

[image: Agents that are idle]

[image: One queued and one waiting]

[image: Queued job]

Comment: Try enabling the preview feature "Historical graph for agent pools". Then, go to your agent pool and hit the Analytics tab. It should show you if you're running into a concurrency (parallel jobs) issue. Also, without seeing your pipeline, I would check to see if you're demanding an agent capability that's only satisfied by one agent in your pool (we do this to restrict certain builds to a certain build "rate").

Comment: The historical graphs while nifty they don't really show any issues/errors that I can see. Ideally it would be nice if we could change that scale and perhaps narrow down to a specific time, ya know?

Comment: You can change the scale down to 1 day and see it on an hourly basis, that's about it.

Comment: Really? Where do you set that? I must have missed it!

Comment: I TOTALLY missed the little filter button! I see it now, thanks for pointing out that option ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current situation, we recommend you can try to check your [Deployment queue settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#stage-triggers), this setting is used to configure actions when multiple releases are queued for deployment. You can select the 'Unlimited':
[image]

Comment: Yujun, thanks for your response, I've made the change and have let the team know they can try and run some builds through again, I will have an update shortly.

Comment: Yujun, we are seeing multiple releases running at the same time now, thanks so much. With 10 self-hosted agents per pool, setting this to unlimited would run the release on any available agent, if we were to flip this from unlimited to specific and set the value to say 5 it would run on any available 5 agents in the pool, correct?

Comment: jeff, if we set to 5, yes, it will use at most 5 available 5 agent to run the multiple releases. This means if you have 6 multiple releases, then 5 will run at the same time, one will wait.